# Make horizontal scrollbar start at right end

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, mcustomscrollbar

In mCustomScrollbar, I want to place the scroller at the right end of horizontal position by default, so I tried this:

```
$('.content').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",'last', {horizontalScroll: true});
```

Which did not work. The following works, but does not move the scrollbar to the right position:

```
$('.content').mCustomScrollbar({horizontalScroll: true});
```

What should I do to make the horizontal scroll appear at right by default?

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot of your scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({advanced:{ // Advanced options
           autoScrollOnFocus: false,
           updateOnContentResize: true, // Scrollbar will be updated on content resize
           updateOnBrowserResize: true  // Scrollbar will be updated on browser resize
        }});
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Check this link to download http://www.4shared.com/document/KxCFmv7E/jquerymCustomScrollbarconcatmi.html

Comment: Actually it does'nt fix my problem of making scroller appear right.Could anyone help on this

Comment: @karthipanraj      have you tried using   direction: rtl; in CSS